# Javascript: Check if a number is within n of another number

Tags: javascript

What is the cleanest way to check whether some variable X is within n numbers of some variable Z.  n is an arbitrary defined number (i.e. 3).

So I want the

```
if (z {something} x){
    // run code if x and z are within 3 of each other
}
```

Comment: Subtract and take the absolute value (`Math.abs()`).

Comment: Wouldnt that be `abs(z-x) < 3` ?Where abs is a function that gets the absolute value.

Comment: How would you do that without coding. What procedure would you do to see if the number is within N? So do that first, after that figure it out in code.... Basic math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the absolute difference of the value and check it.

```
if (Math.abs(x - z) < 3) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the absolute value of the difference of z and x. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp

```
if ((Math.abs(z-x) <= 3){
    // do something
}
```